# preg_match: ensure the start and the end contains something

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to have the regular expression that makes sure the beginning of the string contains 'http://' and '/' and the end.

This is a longer version I came up with,

```
if(!preg_match("/(^http:\/\//", $site_http)) 
{
 $error = true;
 echo '<error elementid="site_http" message="site_http - Your link appears to be invalid. Please confirm that your link contains http:// at the start."/>';
}
elseif (!preg_match("/\/$/", $site_http)) 
{
 $error = true;
 echo '<error elementid="site_http" message="site_http - Your link appears to be invalid. Please confirm that your link has ended with a /."/>';
}
```

but I thought these two expressions can put together like below, but it wont work,

```
if(!preg_match("/(^http:\/\/)&(\/$)/", $site_http)) 
{
 $error = true;
 echo '<error elementid="site_http" message="site_http - Your link appears to be invalid. Please confirm that your link contains http:// at the start and a / at the end."/>';
}
```

the multiple expressions that I try to combine must be wrong! any idea?

thanks,
Lau

Comment: Can you provide a string sample?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/^http:\/\/.*\/$/', $site_http)) 
{
  ...
}
```

The `^http:\/\/` forces `http://` at the front, the `\/$` forces a slash at the end, and `.*` allows everything (and possibly nothing) between.

For example:

```
<?php

foreach (array("http://site.com.invalid/", "http://") as $site_http) {
  echo "$site_http - ";
  if (preg_match('/^http:\/\/.*\/$/', $site_http)) {
    echo "match\n";
  }
  else {
    echo "no match\n";
  }
}
?>
```

generates the following output:

```
http://site.com.invalid/ - match
http:// - no match
```

Comment: blast, you beat me to it. Was typing when it said one new answer. :)